# change DataSource web.xml from derby to postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish

In `web.xml` i try to change my data-source from derby to PostgreSQL, so how can i change this data-source to another data-source using PostgreSQL and `GlassFish`.

```
<data-source>
    <name>java:global/jdbc/CargoTrackerDatabase</name>
    <class-name>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</class-name>
    <url>jdbc:derby:${webapp.databaseTempDir}/cargo-tracker-database;create=true</url>
</data-source>
```

So what should I change in my code to make a data-source to **PostgreSQL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `PostgreSQL`, the driver class name is now `org.postgresql.Driver` and the JDBC URL is of type `jdbc:postgresql://$host:$port/$db-name` knowing that the default port is `5432`.

You can find more details about all the existing parameters that you can provide at the JDBC URL level [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

Comment: Thank you #Nicolas Filotto this will help me